How to make docker container "see" hosts from outside
I have an API in .NET 8 that is a Docker container running inside a virtual machine with the internal IPv4 address 1.1.1.1 (for example).
This API uses a MySQL 8.0.33 database, and this is my connection string:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySQL": "Server=1.1.1.1;Port=3306;initial catalog=db_namel;uid=my-user;pwd=my-pass"
  }

When I run the API locally (by changing the "Server" field value to "localhost"), everything works fine. My problem occurs when I dockerize my API and run it inside my Linux server (Ubuntu 22.04).
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Presentation.Web/Presentation.Web.csproj", "Presentation.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Presentation.Web/Presentation.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Presentation.Web"
RUN dotnet build "Presentation.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Presentation.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Presentation.Web.dll"]

As soon as I create the container for my API on my Ubuntu server, I get the following error:
An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server '1.1.1.1'.
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

To try to solve the problem, I created a new my-user through these commands:
CREATE USER 'my-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-user';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


It is worth mentioning that inside my server (via SSH), I can connect to the database without any issues using the command mysql -u my-user -p.

Later, I deleted the my-user and tried creating it again with the server's internal IP address:
CREATE USER 'my-user'@'1.1.1.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-user';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my-user'@'1.1.1.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

As you can imagine, that didn't work either.
I researched the problem and believe it might have something to do with Docker networks, as according to this answer, "The docker network is for container-to-container communication only". My question is: how can I make my container "see" my connection string correctly?

This problem has nothing to do with mysql or .net. You need to make sure that your containers are accessible from the outside.

This is off-topic on SO

I found the answer. I just need to change the connection string to localhost, for example:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySQL": "Server=localhost;Port=3306;initial catalog=db_namel;uid=my-user;pwd=my-pass"
  }

And I need to add --net=host to docker run command, like this:

docker run -p 8080:8080 --net=host my-image

Doing this, everything works fine!
